# Dynamic Pivot SQL in the Common Table Expression (CTE)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

I am trying to Pivot a result of a CTE. Due to the privacy laws i cannot put my query and resultset here but the example looks like the below:

```
WITH CTE1
AS ( select ....)
,CTE2 
AS (Select...)
,CTE3 
as (Select...)
```

Below is the result of my CTE2:

[image: Dataset1]

and i want the result as

[image: PivotDataset]

The main issue i am having here is to pivot the resultset with **multiple and dynamic Pivot columns between CTE2 and CTE3** as i need to use the Pivot data in CTE3. Is there any solution without changing the CTE's to TempTable? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are those columns dynamic? I get that they're based on types, but are the types not static?

Comment: Yes it is based on type but i don't want to hard code the column names in Pivot. Types gets added frequently and are not static.

Comment: Well, then you either need to convert the entire thing to dynamic SQL or consider not pivoting the data and altering whatever is in your CTE3. Do you _need_ to pivot the data? Because generally a pivot like that is something I'd only worry about for displaying data, not manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be something like this.

```
Dynamic Pivot:
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @years VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT'],[' + [factor_label]
            FROM    [TEMP_lacp_factors]
            ORDER BY '],[' + [factor_label]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [date_],[issue_id],[cusip],[Factor_value],[factor_label]
    FROM [TEMP_lacp_factors]
)t
PIVOT (MAX([factor_value]) FOR [factor_label]
IN ('+@years+')) AS pvt'
EXECUTE (@query)





Dynamic Pivot and Select Into:
-- Drop the table; you create it dynamically
Drop Table tempTable

--Start creating all objects for Dyanmic Pivot
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @years VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT'],[' + [factor_label]
            FROM    [TEMP_lacp_factors]
            ORDER BY '],[' + [factor_label]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
SET @query =
-- Objects that are created above, are put into the table you are about to create below
'SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [date_],[issue_id],[cusip],[Factor_value],[factor_label]
    FROM [TEMP_lacp_factors]
)t
PIVOT (MAX([factor_value]) FOR [factor_label]
IN ('+@years+')) AS pvt) X'
EXECUTE (@query)

-- Select everything from the dynamically created table ('tempTable') to see results
Select * from tempTable
```

I'm not 100% sure what you are doing, so it's just a best guess.